# Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired()

Tags: yii

The following error occurs when running my site. Any ideas what's happening? I am new to Yii and frameworks I don't know what this error means or where it is. I have post my controller along with the error. I've been working on the update action..

Fatal error: Call to a member function isAttributeRequired() on a non-object in C:\xampp\framework\web\helpers\CHtml.php on line 1414

View

```
<?php Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery'); ?>
<?php
/* @var $this BookingController */
/* @var $model Booking */
/* @var $bookingRoom BookingRoom */

$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Bookings'=>array('index'),
$model->Id=>array('view','id'=>$model->Id),
'Update'
);

$this->menu=array(
array('label'=>'List Booking', 'url'=>array('index')),
array('label'=>'Create Booking', 'url'=>array('create')),
array('label'=>'View Booking', 'url'=>array('view', 'id'=>$model->Id)),
array('label'=>'Manage Booking', 'url'=>array('admin'))
);
?>

<h1>Update Booking <?php echo $model->Id; ?></h1>
<a href="create.php"></a>
<?php //$this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?>

<div class="form">
<button id="btnAdd" type='btnAdd'>Add</button>
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'booking-form',
// Please note: When you enable ajax validation, make sure the corresponding
// controller action is handling ajax validation correctly.
// There is a call to performAjaxValidation() commented in generated controller code.
// See class documentation of CActiveForm for details on this.
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>

<p class="note">Fields with <span class="required">*</span> are required.</p>

<?php echo $form->errorSummary(array($model)); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'Id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'Id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'Id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row"> 
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'customerId'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'customerId'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'customerId'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'date'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'date'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'date'); ?>
</div>

    <table id="tblData">
        <tbody>
    <?php foreach($items as $i=>$item): ?>

        <tr>
            <td>
                         <div>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($item,'bookingId'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($item,'['.$i.']bookingId'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($item,'bookingId'); ?>
                </div>
            </td>

            <td>
    <div>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($item,'Room No'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($item, '['.$i.']roomId', CHtml::listData(
    Room::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'id'), array('single'=>'single', 'size'=>5)
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($item,'roomId'); ?>
    </div>
            </td><td>
    <div>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($item,'startDate'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($item,'['.$i.']startDate'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($item,'startDate'); ?>
</div>
                </td><td>
    <div>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($item,'endDate'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($item,'['.$i.']endDate'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($item,'endDate'); ?>
</div>
    </td><td>
    <div>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($item,'adults'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($item, '['.$i.']adults', array('1'=>'1', 
                                                                 '2'=>'2', 
                                                                 '3'=>'3', 
                                                                 '4'=>'4',
                                                                 '5'=>'5'), array('single'=>'single', 'size'=>5)
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($item,'adults'); ?>
    </div>
</td><td>
            <div>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($item,'children'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->dropDownList($item, '['.$i.']children', array('1'=>'1', 
                                                                 '2'=>'2', 
                                                                 '3'=>'3', 
                                                                 '4'=>'4',
                                                                 '5'=>'5'), array('single'=>'single', 'size'=>5)
    ); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($item,'children'); ?>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type='button'>Delete</button>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>   
        </tbody>
    </table>


    <div class="row buttons">
      <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>

<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div><!-- form -->
```

Booking model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "booking".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'booking':
 * @property integer $Id
 * @property integer $customerId
 * @property string $date
 *
 * The followings are the available model relations:
 * @property Bookingroom[] $bookingrooms
 */
class Booking extends CActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'booking';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('Id, customerId, date', 'required'),
        array('Id, customerId', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('Id, customerId, date', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),

    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(       
                 'rooms' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Room', 'id')
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'Id' => 'ID',
        'customerId' => 'Customer',
        'date' => 'Date',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('Id',$this->Id);
    $criteria->compare('customerId',$this->customerId);
    $criteria->compare('date',$this->date,true);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Booking the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
}
```

BookingRoom model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "bookingRoom".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'bookingRoom':
 * @property integer $roomId
 * @property integer $bookingId
 * @property string $startDate
 * @property string $endDate
 * @property integer $adults
 * @property integer $children
 */
class BookingRoom extends CActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'bookingRoom';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('roomId, bookingId, startDate, endDate, adults, children', 'required'),
        array('roomId, adults, children', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('roomId, bookingId, startDate, endDate, adults, children', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(   
                //'booking' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Booking', 'bookingId'),
                //'room' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Room', 'roomId'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'roomId' => 'Room',
        'bookingId' => 'Booking',
        'startDate' => 'Start Date',
        'endDate' => 'End Date',
        'adults' => 'Adults',
        'children' => 'Children',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('roomId',$this->roomId);
    $criteria->compare('bookingId',$this->bookingId);
    $criteria->compare('startDate',$this->startDate,true);
    $criteria->compare('endDate',$this->endDate,true);
    $criteria->compare('adults',$this->adults);
    $criteria->compare('children',$this->children);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord  descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return BookingRoom the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}

public function primaryKey()
{
    return array('roomId', 'bookingId');
}
}
```

Room model

```
<?php

/**
 * This is the model class for table "room".
 *
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'room':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $beds
 */
class Room extends CActiveRecord
{
/**
 * @return string the associated database table name
 */
public function tableName()
{
    return 'room';
}

/**
 * @return array validation rules for model attributes.
 */
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('id, beds', 'required'),
        array('id, beds', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, beds', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array relational rules.
 */
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
               //'bookingrooms' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'BookingRoom', 'roomId'),
                'bookings' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'Booking','bookingroom(bookingId, roomId)'),
    );
}

/**
 * @return array customized attribute labels (name=>label)
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return array(
        'id' => 'ID',
        'beds' => 'Beds',
    );
}

/**
 * Retrieves a list of models based on the current search/filter conditions.
 *
 * Typical usecase:
 * - Initialize the model fields with values from filter form.
 * - Execute this method to get CActiveDataProvider instance which will filter
 * models according to data in model fields.
 * - Pass data provider to CGridView, CListView or any similar widget.
 *
 * @return CActiveDataProvider the data provider that can return the models
 * based on the search/filter conditions.
 */
public function search()
{
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->compare('id',$this->id);
    $criteria->compare('beds',$this->beds);

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the static model of the specified AR class.
 * Please note that you should have this exact method in all your CActiveRecord descendants!
 * @param string $className active record class name.
 * @return Room the static model class
 */
public static function model($className=__CLASS__)
{
    return parent::model($className);
}
}
```

Booking controller

```
class BookingController extends Controller
{
/**
 * @var string the default layout for the views. Defaults to '//layouts/column2', meaning
 * using two-column layout. See 'protected/views/layouts/column2.php'.
 */
public $layout='//layouts/column2';

/**
 * @return array action filters
 */
public function filters()
{
    return array(
        'accessControl', // perform access control for CRUD operations
        'postOnly + delete', // we only allow deletion via POST request
    );
}

/**
 * Specifies the access control rules.
 * This method is used by the 'accessControl' filter.
 * @return array access control rules
 */
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view', 'display'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','delete'),
            'users'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}



/**
 * Displays a particular model.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be displayed
 */
public function actionView($id)
{
    $this->render('view',array(
        'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
    ));
}


    public function getItemsToUpdate($id){
        // create an empty list of records
        $items = array();

            // Iterate over each item from the submitted form                        
            if (isset($_POST['BookingRoom']) && is_array($_POST['BookingRoom'])) {  

                foreach ($_POST['BookingRoom'] as $item) {                        

                    //$item['bookingId'] = $id;
                     // If item id is available, read the record from database 
                    if (( array_key_exists('bookingId', $item) && array_key_exists('roomId', $item) ) && ( array_key_exists('startDate', $item) && array_key_exists('endDate', $item) )){

                        //$items[] = BookingRoom::model()->findByPk($item['bookingId']);
                    //$items[] = BookingRoom::model()->find('bookingId=:bookingId', array(':bookingId'=>$id));
                      $items[] = BookingRoom::model()->findByAttributes(array('roomId' => $item['roomId'], 'bookingId' => $item['bookingId'], 'startDate' => $item['startDate'], 'endDate' => $item['endDate']));
                      //var_dump($items);
                    // Otherwise create a new record
                    } else {

                        $items[] = new BookingRoom();
                    }
            }

                    } 
             else {

                $items = BookingRoom::model()->findAll('bookingId=:bookingId', array(':bookingId'=>$id));

            } 
            return $items;                     
    }



/**
 * Creates a new model.
 * If creation is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 */
public function actionCreate()
{

    $model=new Booking;
            //$BookingRoom=new BookingRoom;
            $items=$this->getItemsToUpdate();

            if (isset($_POST['Booking'])){
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Booking'];
            }
            //var_dump($items);
    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);                                                                              


            if(isset($_POST['BookingRoom']))
              {

                $valid=true;
                foreach($items as $i=>$item)
                {
                    if(isset($_POST['BookingRoom'][$i]))
                    $item->attributes=$_POST['BookingRoom'][$i];
                    $valid=$item->validate() && $valid;
                }

                $valid=$model->validate() && $valid;


                if($valid){

                }                                                                          
              }


    $this->render('create',
                    array('items'=>$items, 'model'=>$model));

}

/**
 * Updates a particular model.
 * If update is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'view' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be updated
 */
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $baseUrl = Yii::app()->baseUrl; 
            $cs = Yii::app()->getClientScript();
            $cs->registerScriptFile($baseUrl.'/js/functions.js');

// first time round
        if (!isset($_POST['Booking'])) {
            $model=$this->loadModel($id);
        } else {

          $model = $this->loadModel($id);
          $model->attributes=$_POST['Booking'];              
          $model->update();
        }

            $items = array();

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);                                                                              


             $items=$this->getItemsToUpdate($id);

            if(isset($_POST['BookingRoom']))
              {

                $valid=true;

                foreach($items as $item)
                {

                }                    

                //$valid=$model->validate() && $valid;

                if($valid){
                        // construct sql save the booking



                }                                                                         
              }

    $this->render('update',
                    array('model'=>$model, 'items'=>$items));

}

/**
 * Deletes a particular model.
 * If deletion is successful, the browser will be redirected to the 'admin' page.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be deleted
 */
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
}

    public function actionDisplay()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Booking');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

/**
 * Lists all models.
 */
public function actionIndex()
{
    $dataProvider=new CActiveDataProvider('Booking');
    $this->render('index',array(
        'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    ));
}

/**
 * Manages all models.
 */
public function actionAdmin()
{
    $model=new Booking('search');
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if(isset($_GET['Booking']))
        $model->attributes=$_GET['Booking'];

    $this->render('admin',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}

/**
 * Returns the data model based on the primary key given in the GET variable.
 * If the data model is not found, an HTTP exception will be raised.
 * @param integer $id the ID of the model to be loaded
 * @return Booking the loaded model
 * @throws CHttpException
 */
public function loadModel($id)
{                        
    $model=Booking::model()->findByPk($id);
            /*
            $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
            $criteria->condition='bookingId=:bookingId';
            $criteria->select = 'roomId';
            $criteria->params=array(':bookingId'=>$_GET['id']);
            $bookingRooms = BookingRoom::model()->findAll($criteria);

            $rooms = array();
            foreach ($bookingRooms as $room) {
                $rooms[] = $room->roomId;
            }

            $model->rooms = $rooms;
            */
    if($model===null) {
        throw new CHttpException(404,'The requested page does not exist.');
            }
    return $model;




}

/**
 * Performs the AJAX validation.
 * @param Booking $model the model to be validated
 */
protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='booking-form')
    {
        echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
        Yii::app()->end();
    }
}


}
```

Stack trace

```
Application Log
Timestamp   Level   Category    Message
15:23:06.388200     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "log" application component
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.400199     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "request" application component
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.409199     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "urlManager" application component
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.436199     trace   system.web.filters.CFilterChain     

Running filter BookingController.filteraccessControl()
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.439199     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "user" application component
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.447200     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "session" application component
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.453200     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "clientScript" application component
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (181)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.483200     trace   system.db.ar.CActiveRecord  

Booking.findByPk()
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (285)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (189)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.483200     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "db" application component
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (285)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (189)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:06.488199     trace   system.db.CDbConnection     

Opening DB connection
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (285)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (189)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.536200     trace   system.db.CDbCommand    

Querying SQL: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `booking`
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (285)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (189)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.556200     trace   system.db.CDbCommand    

Querying SQL: SHOW CREATE TABLE `booking`
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (285)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (189)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.562200     trace   system.db.CDbCommand    

Querying SQL: SELECT * FROM `booking` `t` WHERE `t`.`Id`=23 LIMIT 1
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (285)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (189)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.573199     trace   system.db.ar.CActiveRecord  

Booking.update()
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (191)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.573199     trace   system.db.ar.CActiveRecord  

Booking.updateByPk()
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (191)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.574199     trace   system.db.CDbCommand    

Executing SQL: UPDATE `booking` SET `Id`=:yp0, `customerId`=:yp1,
`date`=:yp2 WHERE `booking`.`Id`=23
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (191)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.666199     trace   system.db.ar.CActiveRecord  

BookingRoom.findByAttributes()
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (77)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (200)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.666199     trace   system.db.CDbCommand    

Querying SQL: SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `bookingRoom`
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (77)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (200)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.685199     trace   system.db.CDbCommand    

Querying SQL: SHOW CREATE TABLE `bookingRoom`
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (77)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (200)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.688199     trace   system.db.CDbCommand    

Querying SQL: SELECT * FROM `bookingRoom` `t` WHERE `t`.`roomId`=:yp0 AND
`t`.`bookingId`=:yp1 AND `t`.`startDate`=:yp2 AND `t`.`endDate`=:yp3 LIMIT
1
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (77)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (200)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)

15:23:07.695199     trace   system.CModule  

Loading "widgetFactory" application component
in C:\xampp\protected\views\booking\update.php (34)
in C:\xampp\protected\controllers\BookingController.php (224)
in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php (13)
```

Comment: please post your view and model files, and also the full stack trace, CHTML is html helper class, Currently your error message there is a problem in rendering the red star to show whether a field is mandatory or not, it could be caused by many types of bugs in your code, without the trace and view and model files not possible to find the issue

Comment: it is probably because your model is **null**

Comment: I have uploaded the view and model files, and the full stack trace.

Comment: The asterisk is still not displaying, so I've removed my last comments.

Comment: The asterisk does not display next to Room No, but displays next to the rest of the required fields. The field is still included in validation. All functionality is there, but the asterisk will not show.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the BookingController::getItemsToUpdate:

```
$items[] = BookingRoom::model()->findByAttributes(array('roomId' => $item['roomId'], 'bookingId' => $item['bookingId'], 'startDate' => $item['startDate'], 'endDate' => $item['endDate']));
```

You can change this query logic or rewrite the code:

```
$model = BookingRoom::model()->findByAttributes(array('roomId' => $item['roomId'], 'bookingId' => $item['bookingId'], 'startDate' => $item['startDate'], 'endDate' => $item['endDate']));
if ($model) {
    $items[] = $model;
}
```